# change clickable coordinate image to css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make the background image of my website clickable in certain coordinates. I dont have the ability of editing the main template as the script im using is prebuilt to add custom code into it (phpfox).

The problem i have is the code i am using is html and i need it to be css

```
<img url="../image/layout/bg.png" width="1920" height="1080" border="0" usemap="#Map" />

<map name="Map">
<!-- #$-:Image map file created by GIMP Image Map plug-in -->
<!-- #$-:GIMP Image Map plug-in by Maurits Rijk -->
<!-- #$-:Please do not edit lines starting with "#$" -->
<!-- #$VERSION:2.3 -->
<!-- #$AUTHOR:ImithRian -->
<area shape="rect" coords="43,36,174,803" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1469,99,1866,225" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/index.php?do=/battlefield4/" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1564,457,1793,619" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/index.php?do=/pages/3/" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1597,657,1773,878" href="http://www.esl.eu/eu/team/7931638/" />
</map>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the coordinates for an image map is just an html feature, not available as a style rule in css. What you can do if you want to change the values of the coordinates without having access to the html is reaching the element via javascript and performing the modifications then. I can provide you that code if you are interested in doing it that way.

---

This is the way you can tackle that with `javascript` ([THE FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9un7r41v/1/))

Let's say you have a world map and you have defined a clickable link for the continents: North America, South America, Europe and Asia, Africa.

```
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--Qn8gNCWlUc/UVhKBl5o5aI/AAAAAAAACYI/wMLgckCYQIs/s1600/Screen+Shot+2013-03-31+at+12.59.10+AM.png" border="0" usemap="#Map" />

<map name="Map">

<area shape="rect" title="north america" coords="43,36,174,803" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/" border="2" />
<area shape="rect" title="south america" coords="1469,99,1866,225" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/index.php?do=/battlefield4/" />
<area shape="rect" title="eurasia" coords="1564,457,1793,619" href="http://www.battlefieldsquad.com/index.php?do=/pages/3/" />
<area shape="rect" title="africa" coords="1597,657,1773,878" href="http://www.esl.eu/eu/team/7931638/" />
</map>

<br /><br />

<button type="button" id="fixer">Fix this mess!</button>
```

When you hover the mouse on the map you notice that just the shape for North America is there and in a wrong position (a tip shows up after a second).

Bellow the map you have a button to fix that. That button execute this code:

```
document.getElementById("fixer").onclick=function(){

    var coords = ["70,100,400,320", "320,350,425,580", "510,100,1050,300", "480,300,680,500"];
    var mapper = document.getElementsByTagName("area");

    for(var i = 0, j = mapper.length;i < j;i++){

        mapper[i].coords = coords[i];

    }

}
```

And once you press the button you can hover the mouse then on the continents and check they are showing up now and in the right position, because the js code changes the coordinates of each shape:

```
var coords = ["70,100,400,320", "320,350,425,580", "510,100,1050,300", "480,300,680,500"];
```

That's an array with the right coordinates for each area shape from top to bottom.

The rest of the code is to set up the coordinates. You just have to edit the above line to meet your own coordinates.

I hope it helps. And by the way, if you are finally going to use this approach, you might want to add the tag javascript to your question. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a pure css-Solution. But if you want to put the image into a div as background, 
you can get the position of a click relativ to your site via jQuery
HTML:

```
<div class="background">
  Some content and a background image
</div>
```

Javascript:

`$('.background').click(function(event){
  console.log(event.pageX + " " + event.pageY);
  //at some coordinate do something (e.g. go to another site)
});`

Comment: I'll also give this a go too. Thanks